# Vagrant and Ansible: ad-hoc command does not work

Tags: vagrant, ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I'm trying to get Ansible and Vagrant working. In a folder (called Vagrant) I have a Vagrantfile, a hosts file and an `ansible.cfg` file with following contents:

`Vagrantfile`

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
# General Vagrant VM configuration.
 config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
 config.ssh.insert_key = false
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

 config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
   v.memory = 256
   v.linked_clone = true
 end

  # Server 1.
 config.vm.define "server1" do |app|
   app.vm.hostname = "server1.dev"
   app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.10"
 end
end
```

Hosts file

```
[server1]
192.168.0.10
```

And `ansible.cfg` file

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
remote_user = vagrant
host_key_checking = False
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<absolute_path_to_folder>/.vagrant/machines/server1/virtualbox/private_key
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
```

When I run the following command, it does not work:

```
macbook-pro:Vagrant user1$  ansible server1 -m command -a uptime
192.168.0.10 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

There seems to be no private key file in the `.vagrant/machines/server1/virtualbox` folder.

When I change the `ansible.cfg` file to

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
remote_user = vagrant
host_key_checking = False
private_key_file = /Users/wauterw/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

it works.

How can I use/create a private key in the `.vagrant/machines/server1/virtualbox/private_key` instead of the general `insecure_private_key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `config.ssh.insert_key = false` or change to `true` as suggested by other answer. This will create a new key whenever you create the instance.

Use hosts file to specify your Ansible connection.

Tested this with `ansible-2.1.1.0` and `Vagrant 1.8.1`:

`ansible.cfg:`

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
host_key_checking = False
```

`hosts:`

```
[server1]
192.168.0.10 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/server1/virtualbox/private_key ansible_user=vagrant
```

Run with `ansible -vvvv` to verify the connection ansible is using. You should see something like:

I.e.

```
<192.168.0.10> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv ... -o 'IdentityFile=".vagrant/machines/server1/virtualbox/private_key"' 
-o User=vagrant
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Vagrant provisioner to insert your own pubkey when you do `vagrant up`

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
# General Vagrant VM configuration.
 config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
 config.ssh.insert_key = false
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

 config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
   v.memory = 256
   v.linked_clone = true
 end

  # Server 1.
 config.vm.define "server1" do |app|
   app.vm.hostname = "server1.dev"
   app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.10"
   app.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "echo <myPubKey> >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys"
 end
end
```

Note: If you use `>>` as I have above, it will keep the insecure key, but if you use `>` it will overwrite the insecure key.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the following line in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

You can also change the value to `true` (which is default; that's why you don't need the line at all).

---

This line actually prevents creating the private key and orders Vagrant to use the default insecure key. Refer to the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html).